# In fix at Microsoft - Name with multiple word does not display fully in chat message

Tags: iphone, microsoft-teams, webbot

So, I'm working on a azure C# web-bot (Company Communicator).
This web-bot send message in a Teams channel.

On PC and Android, when a message is sent the name of the bot is right for exemple: "My multi name app".
But on iPhone, my client send me an image where the name is "My m."

I look on and the only reference I found is https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/issues/6579, but there is no solution yet.
Since the error is the same it should not be a company communicator issue but a teams issue.

I was wondering if someone knew something, maybe a specific checkbox in the AdminTeams, or on the bot configuration, that make IOs display the wrong name.

Edit : Image with some information hidden because the client use real information in a dev env.
It's from the general channel of a teams.
[image]

Comment: As mentioned in https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/issues/6579, does your bot show correct for other responses from bot in iOS client. And shows different only while rendering an adaptive card.

Comment: Well that's kinda a problem, I do not know. 
The client sent an image saying "it does not work" (of the result of the adaptive card in the chat) and it took 2 weeks to know it's an iPhone and I don't have one to work with nor my job...

Comment: Could you please help by sharing the image sent by client. So that we can confirm if the issue happens only when the bot responds with adaptive card. You can edit your question and add the image.

Comment: Thank you, I shared the image but it does not show much except the adaptive card result

Comment: Thank you for sharing required details, we already have bug raised for the above-mentioned scenario where bot with multiple words name does not display fully. We will keep you posted on the updates.